# Java Monitors - Do synchronised methods prevent any other thread being IN that object?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, monitor

Does the following mean that only ONE thread can be in ANY method of the object? Or can a multiple threads be in DIFFERENT methods just not the same one? Why?

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding to the good answers you already have, note that synchronizing, in the same way it prevents any other thread to gain the lock, it prevents as well concurrency, so a class like yours would be slower accessed by multiple threads than accessed only by one, because the threads that do not gain the lock need to be reescheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the following mean that only ONE thread can be in ANY method of the object?

For your specific example, yes, because all the methods are synchronized and non-static.

If your class had any unsynchronized methods, then the unsynchronized methods would not be blocked.

If your class used synchronized blocks instead of methods and synchronized them on different locks, it could get much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the following mean that only ONE thread can be in ANY method of the object?

Yes. Non-static `synchronized` methods implicitly synchronize on `this`. It's equivalent to:

```
public void increment() {
    synchronized(this) {
        c++;
    }
}
```

---

If this were a *real* piece of code [(I know it's not)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), I would recommend throwing out your `SynchronizedCounter` class entirely and using [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, they are `synchronized` on the `this` object. If you had written your own `synchronized` block with different objects for the different methods you have then it won't be the case.